# How to compare jagged array to another array in C?

Tags: c, jagged-arrays

I've been trying to use a jagged array for a project of mine, meanwhile this is just a test furthermore I'll use it in my project. The question is the following How could I compare each element from each array, so in the code below I have three arrays, after them, I have one more which will be used to compare to the first ones,here what I have so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

  int row0[4] = {0,1,3,0};
  int row1[4] = {5,6,9,10};
  int row2[4] = {9,0,1,10};

  int aux[4] = {9,6,9,10};


  int *result[3] = {row0,row1,row2};

  int size[3] = {4,4,4}, k =0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    int *ptr = result[i];

    for (int j = 0; j < size[k]; j++) {


     if(ptr[j] == aux[j])
     {
       printf("%d\n",ptr[j]);
     }

     ptr++;
   }
   printf("\n");
   k++;

   result[i]++;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The result of it is 5, but I'd like to loop over all the values from the array that starts with 5, to find out if the all the other values are equal, in other words I want to know which array is equal to the "aux" array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the (inner) loop:

```
int *ptr = result[i];
for (int j = 0; j < size[k]; j++)
{
     if(ptr[j] == aux[j])
     {
       printf("%d\n",ptr[j]);
     }
     ptr++;
}
```

Since you increment both `j` and `ptr`, you're doing far too much incrementing.  It's probably best to remove the `ptr++;` line.